# error while splitting the file and convert into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, split, numpy-ndarray

Dear experts i want to split a large column of file at the given symbol '>' and make it to numpy array, while doing it with test1.txt file its fine but while applying same script to test2.txt file there is problem like Type-error: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'. but the data structure in test1.txt and test2.txt are same + in both the files data files are separated with same > symbol.Can anybody tell me whats wrong i am doing...i am unable to recognize..my script for test1.txt is given below which works fine.but while i am putting test2.txt instead of test1.txt there is error as mentioned above.My data files(test1.txt and test2.txt) are appended here  https://i.fluffy.cc/4nZ0GdDPjw9v4PdQ5P0C6NhqqGrdd3Wx.html

```
import numpy as np
with open('test1.txt') as f:
    a = f.read()
data = [l.split("\n")[1:-1] for l in a.split('>')[1:]] # 1:-1 removes empty strings
data = np.array(data, dtype=float)
print(data)
```

Comment: When you apply `data = np.array(data)` for both text file then get the results of `data.dtype` for both, it shows `<U10` for *test1.txt* and `object` for *test2.txt*. So, they have different data type.

Comment: can you please suggest how to solve this problem...

Comment: post the expected output

Comment: @deadshot floating point results i expect, as we get results when we apply test1.txt

Comment: your code is not working for both files

Comment: yes @deadshot i need to solve this...you nicely pointed out...is there any solution for the same

Comment: is your output 1d array?

Comment: @deadshot yes two 1d array are separated by the symbol > in both the files(test1.txt and test2.txt)

Comment: @geo You can insert `data = np.array(data, dtype="O")` for the *test1.txt* to make its `dtype` as an *object*.

Comment: @Pooria_T i am getting correct results for test1.txt  there is no doubt....i need to solve same for test2.txt

Comment: @Pooria_T i need float values results as my code does for test1.txt...not strings.is there any solutins for the same

Answer (score 0):

If you like to do it in your own way, refer to below code:

```
with open('test2.txt') as f:
    a = f.read()
data = [l.split("\n")[1:-1] for l in a.split('>')[1:]] # 1:-1 removes empty strings
data_0 = np.array(data[0], dtype='float')
data_1 = np.array(data[1], dtype='float')
data = np.concatenate([data_0,data_1])
print(data)
```

Comment: error ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: I did test it again and get this result `[ 0.019107   0.011177   0.0017088 ... -0.018501  -0.016575   0.       ]`.